# Google Sheets formatting a cell on condition that value in formatted cell is identical to value in another cell

Tags: google-sheets

How do I format a column if the value in each cell in that column matches the value in the corresponding cell in another column.

For Example, A1 says "Cow".  C1 says "Cow".  If that's the case, I want to format A1 to background color blue.

Same thing going down for the entire column.

I have seen other questions related to this which make me think that formatting to

> =A1=B1

should work but it doesn't.  As soon as I type =A1=, it says formula is invalid.
I also tried just =B1 and that had no effect.

All other similar questions have gotten zero up votes or down votes.  Not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Conditional Formatting in cell A1.

Apply to Range

A:A

Custom Formula

=AND(A1=C1,C1<>"")

Set Formatting Style to Blue